# What must $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k}x_{k}y_{k}$ to be an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I am trying to solve the following problem. "Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Under which conditions on $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ does the function $f(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k}x_{k}y_{k}$   define an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ? "

Naturally, $\alpha$ should be such that the standard criteria for the definition of the inner product is satisfied, but is it actually possible to find these conditions for a general $\alpha$? For each given value of $\alpha$ the standard criteria can be tested, but I am struggling how to answer this question for the general case.

Comment: Well, try testing the criteria one by one for general $\alpha$.  You should find that all but one of the criteria are easy and always work.

Answer (score 1):

Bilinearity of $f$ always holds.

If $f(x,x)=0$, then

$$
0=\sum_k \alpha_k x_k^2
$$

We'd like to conclude that each $x_k=0$. What should $\alpha_k$ look like for this to hold?

Comment: Yes that's the criteria I had in mind immediately but I don't see how it works to check what $\alpha$ should be in general case? Suppose $n=3$ ,  and I want to find $\alpha$ such that the above criteria $f(x,x)=0$ does not imply $x=0$. We have $\alpha_{1}x_{1}^{2} + \alpha_{2}x_{2}^{2} + \alpha_{1}x_{3}^{3} =0$ and so $\alpha_{1} = -\frac{\alpha_{2}x_{2}^{2} + \alpha_{3}x_{3}^{2}}{x_{1}^{2}}$, but how does this help? @Reveillark

Comment: Hint: A sum of non-negative numbers is $0$ if and only if each of the summands is $0$. For $n=3$, if you know $a,b,c\ge 0$, then $a+b+c=0$ if and only if $a=b=c=0$. Do you see how this helps?

Comment: I don't see how it helps because some of the $a_{k}$'s can be negative...

Comment: So one possible thing to require of the $\alpha_k$ is that they are non-negative.

Comment: Is this the only requirement here for the full answer? That they are non-negative?

Comment: Not exactly, you need them to be strictly greater than $0$ to conclude that $\alpha_k x_k^2=0\implies x_k=0$.  Note that this also implies $f(x,x)\ge 0$ for all $x$, which is part of the definition.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant to say $\alpha_{k} \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$